# Pointers dynamic Allocation (core dumped)

Tags: c++, pointers

Please help me where I am going wrong, below is my code, before deleting or freeing x it is working fine but after deleting x it is showing me core dumped. I dont know why. what I have done is that i allocated 2 variables in heap with new keyword but then p=x which means that p now holds the address of x. then I am freeing p and at last I am freeing x. Please help me where I am going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

int a;
int *b=&a;
cout<<b<<endl;//address of a

int *x=new int;
cout<<x<<endl;
cout<<*x<<endl;

int *p=new int;

*x=10;
*p=12;

p=x;

cout<<p<<endl;
cout<<x<<endl;
cout<<*p<<endl;
cout<<*x<<endl;

*x=13;
cout<<*p<<endl;

delete p;

*x=14;
cout<<*x<<endl;
cout<<*p<<endl;


delete x;



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you two times delete the same pointer or more precisely the same memory region that is pointed to by two pointers.

After statement

```
p=x;
```

the both pointers, p and x, start to point to the same memory region. Then you at first delete p

```
delete p;
```

and after that you delete x

```
delete x;
```

but the memory pointed to by x was already freed when you deleted p.

And after deleting p all code that follows has undefined behaviour

```
*x=14;
cout<<*x<<endl;
cout<<*p<<endl;


delete x;
```

To avoid this problem you could use smart pointer `std::shared_ptr`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


int main() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> x( new int );
    std::shared_ptr<int> p( new int );

    *x = 10;
    *p = 12;

    p = x;

    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    std::cout << *x << std::endl;

    *x = 13;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;

    *x = 14;
    std::cout << *x << std::endl;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0x95e6008
0x95e6008
10
10
13
14
14
```

Comment: so why after deleting p, *x=14 and cout<<*x is working fine? it is deleted delete p....?

Comment: @user3215228 undefined behavior is undefined. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

After `p=x;`, p and x are pointing to the same location (the one `x` pointed to originally). Calling `delete` on either will render the other one dangling and calling `delete` on it will cause a double free and undefined behavior. `p=x` will also lead to a memory leak, as the memory previously allocated for `p` is no longer reachable.

To just assign the values, not the pointers, do

```
*p = *x;
```